# Height as per resolution in HTML

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have added content div in which having two column div as `col-md-3` and as `col-md-9`

In `<div class="col-md-3">` in between having tabular panel menu and in tabular menu have one accordion with scroll effect.
With having `min-height: 329px !important`

When i check on browser with 1366*768 it looks good with same height

for `<div class="col-md-3"> and for 2nd div`` with same height

but when i change resolution of pc it conflicts

I want same height as per 2nd div having class `.col-md-9`

please give me solution on that.

Comment: Provide a JS Fiddle or add your code for the same,preferrably the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` is the correct solution for you apply this property in parent div like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        // you content here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        // you content here
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    display:flex;
}
```

This will make equal height of elements in `.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class on the divs like this `class="col-md-3 sameheight"` and `class="col-md-9 sameheight"` and than style it giving a static height if this is what you want.

```
.sameheight
{
  height: 300px //for example
}
```

For the responsivnes than you can work with media queries. But also the `display: flex` for the parent of 2 divs is a good solution if it is applicable to you.